# std::vector<T> and basic multithreading design pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vector

I've got my main class: Foo with a variable called

```
 std::vector<Something*> X;
```

and functions

```
 SideThreadUpdate();
 MainThreadUpdate();
```

if I have a `for` loop in my `SideThreadUpdate`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < X.size() ; i++)
{
    X->randomBool = true;
}
```

and a this in my `MainThreadUpdate`:

```
X.push_back(new Something());
```

This will give me access violations and other strange errors. How would I make this thread safe?

I need access to the variable `X` in both threads and I use `boost::thread` for multithreading..

I can't seem to make a `boost::mutex` on  `std::vector<Something*> X;`

Also I'll need continous access to the variable and can't have the MainThread or SideThread waiting..

A simplified example of my use-case; I have 1 thread that I want checking the collisions, and my other thread to handle input and other stuff, both need access to Xl

Comment: Off topic, but you may want to consider `std::unique_ptr<T>` and/or `std::shared_ptr<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a little pattern. Using C++11 `std` library features (but boost should have the same functionality).

```
std::mutex my_mutex;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Something>> X; 

void SideThreadUpdate()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);  // use the same mutex here and
    if(X.size()) X.front()->do_something();
}

void MainThreadUpdate()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);  // here.
    X.push_back(new Something());
}
```

On construction `std::lock_guard<>` acquires the `std::mutex` (or blocks until it succeeds acquiring the mutex) and on destruction releases the mutex. This way, the mutex is automatically released even if an exception is thrown somewhere. You must, however, not try to lock a mutex recursively (on the same thread).

Comment: +1: This is a decent approach, certainly a good 1st attempt at a correct solution. However the problem is it is still possible to gain un-protected access to the vector by simply forgetting to write that line of lock code. In large systems, this is a real problem.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes, bugs are always possible. You may want to design a threadsave vector (and indeed there are several already available, I think tbb has one), the simplest (and least efficient) implementation would simply use a mutex to protect any access.

Answer (score 5):

You need to place a mutex around the access of the vector.  Anytime something is attempting to access the vector, it should first lock the mutex, do the access, and then release the mutex.  This will have to be done in both your `main` and your thread.

You can find an example for boost synchronization [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.tutorial.internal_locking).

Comment: and how do I place a mutex "around the access of the vector"?

I don't really get what you mean with it.

Comment: @Themperror See the link.  The Boost documentation gives a pretty good example, though once you have that implemented, you will probably want to switch to a scoped_lock version.

Comment: Ok, that explains it more clearly..

However I have one question about the program flow..

If I lock a mutex (thus preventing access from the other thread to that object), and the other thread has to access it.. How does it go?, does the thread wait untill it can access it (thus actually causing a pause in the program?) or does it skip it and when it unlocks run that code?

I don't really get how 2 threads can a-synchroniously execute code

Comment: @Themperror:  The 2nd thread blocks until the 1st thread has released the mutex.  See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: +1: This is a decent approach, certainly a good 1st attempt at a correct solution.  However the problem is it is still possible to gain un-protected access to the vector by simply forgetting to write that line of lock code.  In large systems, this is a real problem.

Comment: @JohnDibling Agreed.  Your answer is quite elegant, and it does handle some issues that beginners are not likely to recognize.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward method -- thereby, the easiest to get right on a conceptual level if not an implementation level -- is to pass all access to the `vector` through some kind of synchronization primitive, such as a mutex.

There are many ways to do this.  The simplest & possibly most naive approach is to simply lock down the mutex exclusively for every operation:

```
boost::mutex mtx;
std::vector <Foo> foos;

void ThreadFunction()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock (mtx); 
// we have exclusive access now

  foos.find (...);  
  foos.push_back (Foo (...));
}
```

There are two potential, but major, problems with this approach. First, it serializes access to the `vector`.  Which is to say, if any operation is being performed with or on the `vector`, no other thread can work with it until that work is done.  If you have 2 threads reading from the vector, only 1 can work with it at a time.  The 2nd thread must wait for the 1st thread to relinquish it's lock before it may proceed.  Perhaps this is exactly the behavior you want.  You must decide.

Even if true, there's a second major problem, and that is that in order for it to be correct, you must count on the programmers to ensure the mutex is locked **every single time**.  That's a critical line of code that's easy to forget if the compiler doesn't force you to.  If you have multiple mutexes, they must also be locked in the same order, but that's another story, tangential to this one.

You can fix the second -- and in my view, the bigger problem -- by using the compiler as a firewall against unsafe access.  Let the compiler emit a compiler error and refust to compile if you try to use the `vector` without first locking it down.  Here is a class which does this.  This is also implemented using a Windows [Slim Reader/Writer Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which addresses the first problem --albiet, in a Windows-specific way -- which gives concurrent shared access to multiple threads but exclusive access to only one thread.  You can adopt this code to fit your needs:

```
namespace MT
{
template <typename Object>
class LockingObject
{
public:
    LockingObject ()
    {
        InitializeSRWLock (&mSrwLock);
    }
    virtual ~LockingObject ()
    {
    }

    Object& GetExclusive ()
    {
        AcquireSRWLockExclusive (&mSrwLock);
        return mObject;
    }
    void ReleaseExclusive ()
    {
        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive (&mSrwLock);
    }

    Object const& GetShared ()
    {
        AcquireSRWLockShared (&mSrwLock);
        return mObject;
    }
    void ReleaseShared ()
    {
        ReleaseSRWLockShared (&mSrwLock);
    }

private:
    SRWLOCK mSrwLock;
    Object mObject; 
};


enum LockMode { LM_Exclusive, LM_Shared };
template <LockMode, typename Object> class ObjectAutoLock;

template<class Object> class ObjectAutoLock <LM_Exclusive, Object>
{
public:
    ObjectAutoLock (LockingObject <Object>& lockingObject)
    :
        mLock (lockingObject),
        mObj (mLock.GetExclusive())
    {
    }
    virtual ~ObjectAutoLock()
    {
        mLock.ReleaseExclusive();
    }

    // Access to the controlled map
    Object& get() const
    {
        return mObj;
    }
    operator Object& () const
    {
        return get();
    }

    Object* operator-> () const
    {
        return &get();
    }

private:
    LockingObject<Object>& mLock;
    Object& mObj;
};

template<class Object> class ObjectAutoLock <LM_Shared, Object>
{
public:
    ObjectAutoLock (LockingObject <Object>& lockingObject)
    :
        mLock (lockingObject),
        mObj (mLock.GetShared())
    {
    }
    virtual ~ObjectAutoLock()
    {
        mLock.ReleaseShared();
    }

    // Access to the controlled map
    const Object& get() const
    {
        return mObj;
    }
    operator const Object& () const
    {
        return get();
    }
    Object const* operator-> () const
    {
        return &get();
    }

private:
    LockingObject<Object>& mLock;
    Object const& mObj;
};

}
```

`LockingObject` is the main class here.  If you need to protect a `vector <foo>`, then you would instantiate as `LockingObject <vector <Foo>>` to contain that.  `LockingObject` has a `private` member variable for your `vector`, and so any access to that `vector` must pass through `LockingObject`'s accessor methods.  Those accessor methods simply lock & unlock the synchronization object; the readers return a reference to it.

As a client of this class, you will interface mostly with the `ObjectAutoLock` object, which is an RAII construct.  You construct one of these "on the stack", by passing a reference to the `LockingObject` to it's constructor.  You then can use the `ObjectAutoLock` *as-if* it were actually the `vector`, so the `ObjectAutoLock` gets out of your way.  Once you're done with the `ObjectAutoLock` simply let it fall off the stack and the lock on the `vector` will be released.

I left `public` access to the `LockingObject` accessor methods because that made more sense in my particular usage.  You can make this even safer by `private`-izing those, and making the `ObjectAutoLock` a friend.

As designed, this code would be used like this:

```
typedef std::vector <Foo> Foos;
typedef MT::LockingObject <Foos> LockedFoos;
LockedFoos lockedFoos;

typedef MT::ObjectAutoLock <MT::LM_Shared> SharedFoos;
typedef MT::ObjectAutoLock <MT::LM_Exclusive> ExclusiveFoos;

void ReaderThread()
{
  SharedFoos foos (lockedFoos);  // doesnt return until lock acquired
// we have shared access now.  nobody has exclusive access

  foos.find (...);  // foos can be used like it's a vector now
}

void WriterThread()
{
  ExclusiveFoos foos (lockedFoos); // doesnt return until lock acquired
// we have exclusive access now.  nobody else has any access

  foos.push_back (Foo (...));
}
```

The main benefit of the overall design here is that it makes it easy to use it correctly, difficult to use it incorrectly.  You are using the compiler as a firewall against unsafe access.  You can't get direct access to the `vector` without going through the lock, which is an RAII construct so it will be released properly. If you try to get to the vector directly it will evoke a compiler error.  The slim reader-writer stuff can be swapped out with whichever lock makes sense for your application.

Comment: Boost provides `shared_mutex` which you can use with exclusive `lock`s or `shared_lock`s

Comment: this is very windows specific -- do you have a portable solution?

Comment: @Walter: the important thing here is not the actual code itself but the reasoning behind the design. I'm not trying to give out free fish, but teach self sustainability.